# Фоновая картинка и абсолютное позиционирование

Tags: html5, css3, responsive

Есть блок с фоновой картинкой со сложной структурой, на ней есть геометрические фигуры, мне нужно сделать, чтобы другой текст был в этих "фигурах". Я сделал следующим образом: блоку с фоном задал `position:relative` и `background-size:cover` (разрешение картинки 1200*900), а блокам с текстами абсолютное позиционирование, но в процентах. Но при изменении размера окна браузера[image: введите сюда описание изображения] всё начинает "съезжать". Как такую конструкцию можно сделать адаптивной? На картинке изображена приблизительная схема того, что нужно (красным отображены блоки с абсолютным позиционированием)

Comment: Думаю, стоит тут опубликовать ваш html и css который вы написали, чтоб можно было взглянуть на поведение, видя код, а также , возможно, предложить правки именно к нему, не изобретая колесо

Comment: Можно предложить сделать несколько фоновых изображений и подкладывать нужное при определенном разрешении экрана

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что позиционирование в процентах недостаточно. Насколько я понял, вы поставили `right: 50%`. Верно, в таком случае блок съедет на 50%, однако на 50% начиная от края блока. Возможно на большом разрешении вы не видите, что выравнивание работает криво, однако на мелком это становится очевидно. Для решения вашей проблемы нужно кроме right: 50% поставить еще и `margin-right: -100px`. Где 100px - это половина ширины блока.